# Distance of a vector from a contained subspace (within another supspace)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

I need to find the distance of some $3\times 3$ matrix vector, $B$ (over $\mathbb R$) to a subspace defined as $U=\lbrace A\in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)|trace(A)=0\rbrace$.

The classic way is to apply Gram-Schmidt to find an orthonormal basis for $U$, and then calculate $|| B-Pr_{U}(B)||$. But such basis will consist of 8 vectors, so Gram-Schmidt will be quite tedious.

But I thought I could reduce to $W\subset U$, where $W=\lbrace D\in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)|trace(D)=0\rbrace$ and $D$ is diagonal. it's basis has only 2 vectors and since it is contained in $U$, then $|| B-Pr_{U}(B)||$=$|| B-Pr_{W}(B)||$. Is my assumption right?

Another observation: the inner product is defined as $<A,B>=trace(AB^{t})$, so I can also use the fact that $U=\lbrace A\in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb R)|A\perp \alpha I_{3} , \alpha\in\mathbb R\rbrace$, but I don't see how that helps me.

Comment: His name was 'Gram', not 'Graham'. Something tells me that if you send a matrix to the same matrix with zeros on the diagonal you are orthogonally projecting onto the trace-zero matrix. So the distance between a matrix and its zero-diagonal version should provide the answer. But I'm just guessing here.

Comment: The projection onto a subspace $U$ will in general be different from the projection onto a further subspace $W \subset U$. Just think about a problem in three dimensions [vectors]: the projection onto a plane $U$ and the projection onto a line $W$ in $U$ are different.

Comment: You don’t need to go through G-S to compute a projection matrix. Any basis will do. It’s still a tedious computation, since it will involve products of $8\times9$ matrices. Angryavian’s answer below is best, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last paragraph is the most useful observation. Think about how you would project a vector onto a hyperplane $\{v \in \mathbb{R}^n : v \perp b\}$ for some fixed $b$. The story is the same here.

I think the projection can be written as $A - \frac{1}{3} \langle A, I_3 \rangle I_3$, i.e. project $A$ onto the orthogonal direction $I_3$, and subtract from $A$.